Does the F/A-18 use the MBU-20/P oxygen mask?
As the title suggests,my question is if the F/A-18 uses MBU-20/P

Wouldn't you be able to put whatever mask you want on the end of the O2 hose? ("You" in this case probably being an organization, not necessarily an individual.)

@RalphJ I have hard that certain aircraft only work with certain O2 masks for example as far as I know,over here in Romania we have the IAR-99SM that can only use the MBU-20/P

If you are able to recognize it by appearance I would suggest looking on YouTube for F-18 catapult shot videos.  There are a lot that show the pilot from inside the cockpit.
